# How to build data frames in different tabs instead of doezns of textOutputs?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm a beginner on R and Shiny and I would like to adapt a code I've found with Shiny examples, please type `runExample("05_sliders")` on console to see it.

I would like to get a table as the one on the right of the screen, but with variables I would have chosen and in 2 different tabs, because I'll have dozens of variables to show finally, but I can't manage to do it.

I have created 3 tabs : `Selection`, `Gear` and `Carb`.
I have a `checkboxGroupInput` in the `Selection` tab where I chose between 4, 6 or 8 cylinders.
Once I have made my choice, I would like 2 different data frames :
- one in "Gear" tab, where is shown the number of cars which have 3, 4 or 5 gears, and the number for which "vs" = 0 or 1,
- one in the "Carb" tab I would like to have the number of cars of each "carb" value and the number of cars of each "am" value.

But it doesn't work at all and I don't understand why.
If you could give me help please.

This is the code :

```
Ui.R
library(shiny)

shinyUI(navbarPage("MTCARS",
               tabPanel("Sélection",
  checkboxGroupInput("dynamic", label = "Cars",
             choices = list("4 cylinders" = 4, "6 cylinders" = 6,
                            "8 cylinders" = 8)),
               tabPanel("Gear",
                       mainPanel(
                         tableOutput("Gear")),

               tabPanel("Carb",
                        mainPanel(
                          tableOutput("Carb")
                        ))))))

Server.R
library(shiny)
# Define server logic
function(input, output) {

# Reactive expression to compose a data frame containing all of
# the values
selection_cylinder <- reactive({
filter(mtcars, cyl %in% input$dynamic)
})
selection_cylinder <- reactive({
filter(mtcars, cyl %in% input$dynamic)
})

# Compose tab "Gear" data frame
data.frame(
  Name = c("Gear", 
           "vs"),
  Value = as.character(c(input$dynamic, 
                         input$dynamic), 
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE))

# Compose tab "Carb" data frame    
data.frame(
  Name = c("Carb",
           "am"),
  Value = as.character(c(input$dynamic,
                         input$dynamic),
  stringAsFactor=FALSE))

# Show the values of the "Gear" data frame using an HTML table
output$Gear <- renderTable({
selection_cylinder()
})

# Show the values of the "Carb" data frame using an HTML table
output$Carb <- renderTable({
selection_cylinder()
})
}
```

It doesnot function at all, so if you could give me a help please.

I'm a little bit lost.

Thank you very, very much to everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works for what you want, creating the tabs for your dynamic output. The order of the panels needed to be re-arranged and the data frames pulled into reactive elements:

`Server.R`:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
# Define server logic
function(input, output) {

# Reactive expression to compose a data frame containing all of
# the values
selection_gear <- reactive({
x.gear=filter(mtcars, cyl == input$dynamic)
x.table=table(x.gear$gear)
x.vs=sum(x.gear$vs)
# Compose tab "Gear" data frame
data.frame(
  Name = c(unique(x.gear$gear),
           "vs"),
  Value = as.character(
    c(x.table, 
        x.vs), 
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
})
selection_carb <- reactive({
y.carb=filter(mtcars, cyl == input$dynamic)
y.table=table(y.carb$carb)
y.am=sum(y.carb$am)
# Compose tab "Carb" data frame    
data.frame(
  Name = c(unique(y.carb$carb),
           "am"),
  Value = as.character(c(y.table,
                         y.am),
  stringAsFactor=FALSE))
})

# Show the values of the "Gear" data frame using an HTML table
output$Gear <- renderTable({
selection_gear()
})

# Show the values of the "Carb" data frame using an HTML table
output$Carb <- renderTable({
selection_carb()
})
}
```

`ui.R`:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(navbarPage("MTCARS",
        tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("Sélection",
                radioButtons("dynamic", label = "Cars",
                choices = list("4 cylinders" = 4, "6 cylinders" = 6,
                    "8 cylinders" = 8))),
                tabPanel("Gear",
                    tableOutput("Gear")
                ),
                tabPanel("Carb",
                    tableOutput("Carb")
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Hello desc, thanks to you, I'm near my goal, thank you very much. I just modified the Carb tab because I would like to get the number of cars of each value of Carb (Carb1, 2, 3, 4, 6 and 8) of the number of cylinders I have choosen. Would you know how can I do to get these values please ? Thank you very much.

Comment: hey @Mickey_NC, the new code should work for the logic you wanted, and will display based on the the cars in the filtered list.

Comment: The logic breaks when multiple inputs are checked, so I switched to `radioButtons` instead of `checkboxes`.

Comment: It's a shame that multiple inputs are impossible, but you told me how to do what I was looking for, and thank you very very much for that. Have a very nice day.

Comment: More I meant that the logic I used wasn't ideal for multiple inputs, with some work and some fiddling, that code should get you to what you want. Best of luck!

Comment: Thinking on it, a `for` loop might help you. If this did answer your question, please mark it as [answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try to adapt the code, thank you very much for helping desc.